# Fedora: How do I force all installed packages to a single release version?

Tags: fedora, dnf

I'm running Fedora 28. To install one package which I knew was broken in Fedora 28, I used a package from Rawhide. This package pulled in hundreds of dependencies and all were installed at their current version in Rawhide. At the end of the installation, the original package failed to install, leaving all of the dependencies installed at release version 29. While troubleshooting, I was able to get the version of the package from Fedora 28 to work, so I no longer need the dependencies to be at their current versions. I would like to downgrade them back to their current version in Fedora 28, but the list is far, far too long to type by hand.

Is there a way to sync all packages to a single release version in DNF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `dnf(1)` man page:

> ```
>    dnf distro-sync [<package-spec>...]
>           As  necessary  upgrades,  downgrades or keeps selected installed
>           packages to match the latest version available from any  enabled
>           repository.  If  no package is given, all installed packages are
>           considered.
> ```